# Tikz-node does not print the number in sans-serif fonts after rounding

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to print a rounded number in a tikz-node in sans serif font. However, it does not work. How can I round the number and print it in sans serif?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {3.14}; %how it should be
    \node at (1,1) {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=2]{3.14159265358979323}}; %not working
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Look at section 92 of the manual 'Number Printing'. I guess you probably want to change the format used. Note that the number is printed in *maths mode* which normally means serif. You could just get the result into a variable and then print it normally. Or you might want to change maths mode for the document as a whole, I guess. Changing `\familydefault` just changes the default for *text*. It doesn't do anything to *maths*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use option `assume math-mode` for `\pgfmathprintnumber`. Then there is no automatic switch to math mode and the number is printed as-is.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {3.14}; %how it should be
    \node at (1,1) {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=2,assume math mode]{3.14159265358979323}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\mathsf`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {3.14};                  
\node at (1,1) {$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=2]{3.14159265358979323}}$};           
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Or you can load `sansmath` and enable locally `\mathversion{sans}`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\mathversion{sans}
\node at (0,0) {3.14};
\node at (1,1) {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=2]{3.14159265358979323}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]